# bootstrap button with error in adding simple onclick event and javascript function

Tags: javascript, button, bootstrap-4, onclick, buttonclick

I have the following bootstrap button in a nav bar.

```
<button type="button" onclick="loginfunction()" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
```

The corresponding javascript function (placed beneath it) is:

```
<script>
function loginfunction() {
  windowalert("Login functionality is under development.");
}
</script>
```

I know how to call a function from a button, for instance the following would work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="this.innerHTML=Date()">The time is?</button>

</body>
</html>
```

but in this case the error is to do with the additional existing code I had in and I wasn't sure of the syntax.

For this snippet of code:

```
  <button type="button" onclick="loginfunction()" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
```

DO I have to remove button type="button" and directly code ? I have tried a few things but keep getting an error.

For instance, I tried this, with no desired result,also doing this removes the bootstrap styling as I removed the class information.

```
<button type="onclick"=loginfunction() class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
```

The whole code in context, if useful is below. This shows the nav bar and you'll note the login button toward the bottom with the script for the loginfunction *onclick event* underneath the button html.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><Vsiteclass="tk"></VSite></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>f
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Symptom checker</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <span class="navbar-text">
        <button type="onclick"=loginfunction() class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>

<script>
function loginfunction() {
  windowalert("Login functionality is under development.");
}
</script>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Signup</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want it to remain a bootstrap button with the class style, so need to keep the:

```
<button type="button"
```

Comment: Have you tried it with removing button type ?

Comment: @Shivam Shukla - I've tried various things - please post a solution so I can verify if you're attempting an answer? :) I've also explained I don't want to remove button type as I want to keep the class (style) from bootstrap for the button

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it out:**

Had an error in the script (window.alert not windowalert)

```
<script>
function loginfunction() {
  window.alert("Login functionality is under development.");
}
</script>
```

**And I was missing a semicolon ...**

```
<button type="button" onclick="loginfunction();" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>
```

The positioning of the JavaScript did not matter that is it could be above or before the button and it still worked.

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions, not even your own